# Advertising Network and API

Tags: api, ads

I was wondering if there exists some sort of advertising network with an API. I would like to try an integrate ads into web games but need total control over the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [OpenX](http://www.openx.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Admob? or are we talking about Ads that you can control?